# Accessing specific record of database according selected datagridview after filter

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datagridview, datatable

My datagridview filled with main fields from database table.

```
DataTable dt2 = db.select("select fname,lname from tbl_actor"); 
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt2;
```

By click on datagridview all fields of record will shown on separate textboxs.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
DataTable dt3=new DataTable();
dt3.Clear();
dt3 = db.select("select * from tbl_actor where fname='" +dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'and lname='" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "'");
tbxtemp1.Text = dt3.Rows[0][1].ToString();
tbxtemp2.Text = dt3.Rows[0][2].ToString();
tbxtemp3.Text = dt3.Rows[0][3].ToString();
}
```

It is OK. But we have another textbox that will filter contents of datagridview

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DataTable dt2 = db.select("select * from tbl_actor where fname like '%" +textBox1.Text+"%'");
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt2;
}
```

Problem is here. after filtered data shown, dataGridView1_CellContentClick event stop with error.

**"There is no row at position 0"**

I know the problem is from datatable but don't know how to solve it

Comment: Before you do anything else you need to read about, understand, and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables decimates your database. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: As for the issue at hand there is no chance anybody can answer this without a lucky guess. What do you want to happen when the query returns nothing? You need to provide a lot more in the way of details here.